# What type of primer is required for pine?

Tags: painting, primer, pine

I bought a gallon of Zinsser, low-odor, stain-and-odor-blocking, oil-based, primer. We bought it primarily for the subfloor we found after tearing out the carpet and seeing some various pet stains.

I also built a new mantle as part of the room remodel out of pine. It's quality pine, but still a knot or two. Is any oil based primer sufficient to fully cover pine or do I need to go with some special just for pine?

Comment: If you're asking specifically whether you can use that particular Zinsser product, please provide an exact name or a link to the relevant page on their website.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought Zinsser Cover-Stain, that is about the best option for any type of wood.

[Cover-Stain](https://www.rustoleum.com/CBGProduct.asp?pid=222)

Answer (score 0):

A primer that's specifically designed to cover and seal soft, sappy wood is important. Some products will not result in a uniform finished surface, and some will allow bleeding of sap after the fact. You'll need to read labels or provide more specific information about your product.